# Cannot define default value for my select using ng options and ng init

Tags: angularjs

i don't know why it is not working when i want to precise a default value in my select:

```
<select ng-init="action1 = skills[0].name"
                    ng-model="action1" ng-options="skill.name for skill in skills">
            </select>
```

Even with:

```
<select ng-init="action1 = action1"
                    ng-model="action1" ng-options="skill.name for skill in skills">
            </select>
```

In my controller, i automatically load an user after a server request.

```
$scope.user = dataFromServer;
$scope.action1 = $scope.user.action1;
$scope.skills = $scope.user.skills;
```

My user have an array "skills". I can choose a skill in my select and i store the item choosen in $scope.action1. But if $scope.user.action1 is already set i want to have my select with this value as default.

I want to use ng-init and ng-options.
Please help ^^

Answer (score 0):

It should be without the `.name`:

`ng-init="action1 = skills[0]"`

and the `skills` array should be fetched before the compilation of the `ng-init` directive you may use something like:

`<select ng-if="skills.length" ng-init="action1 = skills[0]"` notice the `ng-if`

Comment: Thanks it works with the ng-if and the skills[0]. But i have only the first element of the array (obviously i set to [0]). How can i have the value inside $scope.action1?

Comment: (I mean i want the $scope.action1 as default value in my select. And If later my server returns a new value inside $scope.action1)

Comment: What do you mean by >> "If later my server returns a new value inside $scope.action"

Do you mean update the selected option? you can do from the controller $scope.action1 = [new Object];

Comment: But you will face an issue with the `ng-if` isolated scope you can do that


Controller:
`$scope.selectModels = {};`

Views:
`ng-init="selectModels.action1 = skills[0]"`
`ng-model="selectModels.action1"`

Now you can access `$scope.selectModels.action1` form the controller, you can reassign its value after the success of your skills request